# PHP DOM: Get Nodevalue without descendant nodes

Tags: php, xml, dom, nodes, nodevalue

i am using the php dom function `nodeValue` to extract the text of content. But it returns the descendant values too:

```
<example>
<inhalt>123<more>45</more></inhalt>
</example>
```

return for `inhalt` 12345 and 123 as i prefer. I know that is not the sense and not very well to have text inside `inhalt` but how i check that there is no text in `inhalt` like `hasNodeValue`?

Comment: what's your requirement is if there's a third number 45</more>67</inhalt> ?

Comment: Keep in mind that text is a node too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Phil mentioned text is also organized in nodes. Therefore your node *inhalt* has two children: A text node ("123") and an element node named *more*, which also has a text node ("45").

If you just want to know, if there is text before the element *more*, test if there is at least one element and then test if the first element is text (should be *DOMText* as far as I remember).

If you like to know, if there is at least one element "at the root", iterate over all children and make the same tests.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domtext.php